# How to show the featured image of a post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

This is the plugin code for showing the respective post related to wp_ai1ec_events

```
function draw_event($atts ) {



            global $wpdb;

            $event = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  wp_ai1ec_events ORDER BY start");

            foreach ( $event as $events ) 

{

     $events1=$events->post_id;

     $wpdb->show_errors();





    $list=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID =$events1");

    $url = site_url();

    $title=str_replace(' ', '-', $list->post_title);

    $title=str_replace('/', '', $title);

    $start = explode(" ", $events->start);

    $end = explode(" ", $events->end);
    $img_src=wp_get_attachment_image($events1);
    $result.=$img_src."<p><strong><a style='color:#FFF' href='".$url."/ai1ec_event/".$title."' >".$list->post_title."</a></strong></p> <img src='".$img_src."'/>  Start date:".$start[0]."<br> Time:".$start[0]."</br>End date:".$end[0]."<br> Time:".$end[1]."<br><br><br>";  

}

    return $result;     

        //print_event($events,$list);



            }



add_shortcode( 'listtheevent', 'draw_event');
```

Now i want to show the featured image of the respective post. I am using wp_get_attachment_image($events1); for this. But this does not work

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Googling something like `wordpress show featured image`? That what I always do when stuck with a WP job and it mostly works fine

Comment: Ok i had googled and find solution $events1 get_the_post_thumbnail($events1, 'thumbnail');

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CODEX for post thumbnails (featured Images)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails